# vlookup return array (formula only, no code please)

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I have a table like so:

```
A   B   C   D
1   3   2   1
2   3   2   1
3   0   2   2
```

I want to vlookup the first column so that it returns the 3 columns after.

For example if I look up `2`, i want the return to be `3 2 1`.

i need it in one formula because it will go into a `sumproduct` expression.

Does not have to be a `vlookup`. I just need something that will return me an array though some type of indexing or lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to achieve this is [`query`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343). So for the data given by you (A, B, C are column), you can use the following formula to get all three columns for the lookup value `2`

```
=QUERY($A$1:$D$3,"select B,C,D where A = 2")
```

Then you can apply any aggregate function on top of this too. For eg:

```
=sum(QUERY($A$1:$D$3,"select B,C,D where A = 1"))
```

Check this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ltbC_wDaZVdfDeFUex0qyFgjO35oc1DdbTCRZSo7ayE/edit#gid=0)